# Trouble with upgrade to LibreOffice Calc

Tags: updates, libreoffice

Yes, I tried to ask this question on AskLibreoffice but it's horribly frustrating trying to get anything posted with the hundreds of Are you a robot? 'find this find that'? tests where the pictures are so bad you can hardly make out anything let alone what they ask for. GAH! Why do they think they need that every step you take? Very frustrating that they think they need that much security AFTER you've logged in!

Anyway, this is a Ubuntu 20.04 install, new, full, that came with Libreoffice Calc and when I try to open CALC, I get this error meassage:

“Automatic update of external links has been disabled...Allow updating X”

I have tried clicking the X to allow; deleting the links than navigating to and using the cells I'm trying to update from to the new cells; AND I've checked the "Options, Calc, General, ALLOW". I even tried turning that off, shutting Calc down than restarting it and turning it back on. To no avail. The problem is there whenever I start CALC.

This issue CAME with Ubuntu 20.04 as I didn't have the problem in 14-16-18.04.

Any help?

Thanks...

Screen Shot of error message displayed EVERY TIME the SS is opened. It changes which link it's ignoring occasionally. First it was all 6 of them, now it's down to just 2. And by that I mean when I click on 'Allow...' it cycles through the links it's troubled by. I've tried relinking them all several times, sometimes it works, but there's still two that it refuses.

[image: Sample Spreadsheet showing error message]

Opps, I didn't put all the messages in yesterday, here's what displays if I click on the Allow button:

[image]

Comment: Is this message associated with a specific document? Can you post of screenshot of the message?

Comment: @xiota: It's associated with my main XLS spreadsheet. I use the same one all year long, and then xfer to a new copy on Jan 1st. I use XLS because sometimes I share the sheet as an example of how it's set up with my peers and most of them use Windoze. I'll get a screen shot but it's exactly what I show above, except it's yellow with '!' in the front. Anyway, BRB. DOH! Forgot, it's on the other computer. I'll have to fire that up and get it from there. But I've errands to run that won't wait. Sorry!

Comment: Can you create and upload a sample document that exhibits the problem?

Comment: @xiota: Sorry, I've had to go to the hospital a couple times and I'm not working very fast. I don't see where I can attach that screen shot in a comment so I'll add it to my original post...as far as creating a sample doc, wow, I'll have to beg off for a while. Just not healthy enough ATM. Can't sit at my computer for more than a few minutes. Thanks for helping tho, and hope you'll stick with me for a while as I have to get this fixed before Jan 1 when I roll all my SS's over to the new year.

Comment: It's probably something in the document, an "external link" that needs to be updated.   I don't know what it is, but once you find it, you should be able to update it and the problem should go away...  If your document is pulling from an external data source, you may have to change a setting to allow it...  Hope you feel better... The internet will still be here when you get back.

Comment: Okay...thanks. Here's the deal, the links are formed by the simple operation of clicking a cell putting = there, then navigating to the other spreadsheet and clicking on the cell with the info I want the target SS to include. Doing that operation puts a long long link in the target cell. So I never type it manually, I always use the navigation method...with both SS's open side by side. The SSs are in the same directory. I've 're-inserted' several times now, and of the 6 links I had that were complaining originally, only 2 remain. Scn Shot above.